# why I can't find get my data in Laravel blade

Tags: php, html, laravel

This is my error:

> Undefined variable: salesdate (View: C:\Users\jingh\blog\resources\views\layouts\home.blade.php)

This is my `home.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.login')

@section('content')
{{ csrf_field() }}

<h1>Laravel</h1>
  @foreach ($salesdate as $key => $value)
      {{ $value->grand_price }}
  @endforeach
@endsection
```

I already add my model inside

```
use App\Sales;
```

This in my controller

```
public function dateview()
{
    $salesdate = Sales::whereDate('created_at', '2019-03-13')->get();

    return view ('layouts/home', [
      'salesdate' => $salesdate
    ]);
}
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('/sales/{id}/dateview', 'SalesController@dateview')->name('sales.dateview')->middleware('auth');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

How to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: In such a case you could do a step by step debugging,

 1. First put `echo 'hi';exit();` in the dateview function to see if this function is being called.
 2. Check with the value of your `$salesdate` variable, if that seems fine, throw in a simple variable `$myName='John Doe'` and send just this variable in the view to see if you are able access it.
 3. Otherwise hard-code the $salesdate variable and check if that value is accessible in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes, you tell it to use the `index()` method,

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

But in your controller, you have named it `dateview()`. The route should be

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@dateview' )->name('home');
```

Comment: i get it now but why i cant do it in SalesController? then use the home index? thx for help

Comment: Because in your sales controller the method you want to use is probably named `index()`

Comment: using this can make a sum(daily, monthly and yearly) revenue?

Comment: That's logic that you add in the controller, then pass those values to the view.